# KVM guest host communication Ubuntu virtual server

Tags: networking, virtualization, hosts

I have tried a few solutions so far but cannot get this working:
I have a couple virtual servers running on my client machine.  I seem to be able to connect the guests to the host or the guests to guests but not both.  I am running Ubuntu 16.04 on everything.  I am using Wok/Kimchi to manage everything.  In Wok I created a MACVTAP and a NAT interface.  As a test I have three virtual servers, two of which are using the macvtap and one that has both the nat and macvtap.  The macvtap servers can ping each other and can ping the internet but cannot ping the host or the virtual server running both nat and macvtap.  I am assuming my problem lies in how I am configuring the machine with multiple interfaces.  Ideally I want all these machines to connect to each other, the host, and the internet.

On the nat/macvtap maching my output from ifconfig -a shows an ens3 and an ens7 device.  How should I setup my /etc/network/interfaces?

Comment: Your tool should have warned you that macvtap does not work for guest-to-host communication. If you need this, set up a bridge on the host instead, and have your guest's network interface connect to the bridge.

Comment: Actually I ended up using macvtap on 3 VMs and they all can talk to each other, the internet, and the host